# Globals and Functions... and Kivy (Python 2.7.10) (Kivy 1.9.1)

Tags: python, kivy, global

I'm trying to use `Kivy` to add a GUI to some script. However, the following is stalling me significantly:

```
class SearchScreen(Screen):
    search_input = ObjectProperty()

    users_dic = {}

    def search_user(self):
        globals()["users_dic"] = GetSessionToken.find_user(
        self.search_input.text, agent_head)

        print globals()['users_dic']

        users = [key for key in users_dic.iterkeys()]

        self.search_results.item_strings = users

        self.search_results.adapter.data[:]
        self.search_results.adapter.data.extend(users)
        self.search_results._trigger_reset_populate()

    class userButton(ListItemButton):
        pass

    def getUserSession(self, user):
        global current_user, user_header, session_token

        current_user = user

        users_dic = globals()['users_dic']

        print users_dic

        try:
            user_header, session_token = GetSessionToken.UserSession(
            users_dic[user], agent_head)
            return self.root.changeScreen("operations")
        except ValueError:
            return self.root.changeScreen("denied")
```

It produces this error:

```
 KeyError: 'users_dic'
```

I do not understand why this is working for `"search_user"` but not for `"getUserSession"`. To confirm, "search_user" prints out the dictionary:

```
{u'user1': u'202703', u'user2': u'202702', u'user3': u'201105'}
```

I want to be provided with "202703" when I run "getUserSession('user1')". What am I missing about `Globals`? What are the differences between the way the functions are handling "users_dic"?

EDIT:

`search_user` is being called in the Kivy language file as follows:

```
<SearchScreen@Screen>:
    search_input: search_box
    search_results: search_results_list
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        BoxLayout
            height: root.height/10
            size_hint_y: None
            TextInput:
                id: search_box
                size_hint_x: 75
            Button:
                text:"Search"
                size_hint_x: 25
                on_press: root.search_user()
```

`getUserSession` is being called within the Kivy language file as follows:

```
<userButton>:
    on_press: main.SearchScreen().getUserSession(self.text)
```

Comment: Using global variables like this is generally considered bad style. You can instead use e.g. an attribute of the class your methods have in common.

Answer (score 1):

In `search_user` you have set a value to `Globals["users_dic"]`, therefore you were able to access it, when your code reached `getUserSession` `user_dic` is not yet defined in `Globals`.

If you had called `search_user` prior to calling `getUserSession`, you should be able to access `users_dic` as part of the `Globals`, like shown in this example:

```
class Foo():
    def test(self):
        globals()['test'] = 'test'
    def post_test(self):
        print globals()['test']

foo = Foo()
foo.test()
foo.post_test()
>>test
```

Just to be clear, setting `users_dic` in the class scope doesn't make it part of `Globals`.

Comment: thank you for your reply. This confuses me as I run `search_user` first, so there must be a value to reference? Further to this I should probably explain that I was initially declaring `global user_dict` at the start of both functions (with the appropriate code used thereafter) and failed with the same error. I was  simply testing the `globals()` method at time of posting this.

Comment: Certainly, I have now updated my answer to include the calls to the functions. Though they are in the KV language file.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the KV language, try to verify `search_user` is being called first and on the same module scope. Sorry for not being more helpful.

Comment: no worries, I sincerely thank you for looking. I have limited it to the fact the ListItemButton does not pass with `<Screen name="SearchScreen">` but rather `<Screen name = "">` , though I am still unsure of how I can solve this whilst maintaining the functionality of the buttons.

Comment: @JJA please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful for you by clicking the check-mark.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who may stumble across an issue similar to mine, I worked around the problem by moving the function to be within the root widget, and changing the event to reference this instead.

This means moving the function from being within:

```
class SearchScreen(Screen):
```

to being under:

```
class AgentAppRoot(BoxLayout):
```

Then changing the event from:

```
on_press: root.getUserSession(self.text)
```

to:

```
on_press: main.SearchScreen().getUserSession(self.text)
```

I am unsure as to why this has worked, but it has... for now. For anybody in my position I regret I am unable to offer anything further.